# Rails ActiveRecord select distinct records ordered by timestamp

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, distinct-on

In the following table of data:

[image]

I am trying to select from this table the records that are distinct based off of the columns `itemable_id`, `itemable_type`, and `user_id`. I also want the records sorted by `last_viewed_at`. In rails, I have been able to get the records to be distinct, but every way I try always gets record ID `1` instead of `4` for `ThingType1` that has `itemable_id 32`. Essentially, the record set iI'm trying to end up with is one with rows with IDs 4, 3, and 2. How can i do this efficiently?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [group](https://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/group) to get a group of distinct records and then order them by `asc` or `desc` -

```
UserItemView.select(:user_id, : itemable_type, :itemable_id).group(:user_id, : itemable_type, :itemable_id).order(last_viewed_at: :desc)
```

Comment: Unfortunately that gives me a `#<ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "user_item_views.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: SELECT "user_item_views".* FROM "user_item_views" GROUP BY "...` error

Comment: Yup, i'm running this: `UserItemView.group(:itemable_id, :itemable_type, :user_id).order(last_viewed_at: :desc)`

Comment: I have updated the answer, can you please try that?

Comment: now i get `#<ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "user_item_views.last_viewed_at" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: ..._type", "user_item_views"."itemable_id"  ORDER BY "user_item...`.

It keeps wanting the other columns in the group by only if i add them it would defeat the point of the group cause those are unique columns

Comment: You can use `sort_by` instead of `order ` - UserItemView.select(:user_id, : itemable_type, :itemable_id).group(:user_id, : itemable_type, :itemable_id).sort_by{| last_viewed_at |}